# Rotating a shape in VBA change its dimensions, but not when rotating with the property window

Tags: excel, vba, rotation

*I had this weird bug, which I spend hours to figure out, so I'm documenting the solution for the next person.*

**Issue:**

When using Excel 2019, I had this issue where if I make 2 copies of the exact same shape, rotate one with the property toolbar in excel and the other with VBA code (shape.rotate), the one rotated in VBA would be **slightly** resized.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Set your zoom to 96%
2. Create a rectangle
3. Make a copy of that rectangle.
   3.5 Place it on top of the other one so they are roughly in the same position. (Not important, but will help to visualize the issue)
4. Right click on the first rectangle, open the Shape Format sidebar. Using the 3rd tab, enter 45 as rotation value
5. Using VBA, rotate the other shape 45 degrees.
6. Both shape won't have the same dimension
   6.5 Using the Shape Format way, rotate each shape back to 0. Both shapes won't have the same dimensions.

Note: For me the issue occured at 45 degrees, it might be different for you.

**Solution:**

I read [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-vba-shape-rotate-makes-unwanted-move-and-resize-to-shape/m-p/722128) that it could be caused by the application zoom not being 100%. And sure enough, I was at 96%. Adding the following code before doing a rotation in VBA fixed the issue for me:

```
If Not ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 Then
    If MsgBox( _
        "Zoom other than 100% sometime cause small inacuracies during rotation." & vbCrLf _
        & vbCrLf _
        & "Restaure zoom to 100% ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 'Set the zoom to 100%
    End If
End If
```

If anyone has a better way to fix this issue (ie: without having to force the zoom to 100%), I'm leaving the answers open.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue (in Excel Mondo 2016). Can you show, please, the code slice witch declares, sets and rotates the respective shape?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I'm not using that version of Excel. Mine is 2019 I think, not Mondo for sure. Just simply: ActiveSheet.Shapes("myRect").rotation = 45. But I'm pretty sure this issue depends on a lot of variable (screensize, window size, zoom value). In my specific case, it was happening around 45 and -45. Just off by a few pixels.